# How to count students who got equal marks and also show the marks of that group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `Marks` table containing students names and marks. I want to group all the students who got same marks. I also want to write the marks they got as given below.

The sample table is

```
╔═════════════════════╗
║ StudentName   Marks ║
╠═════════════════════╣
║ A             90    ║
║ B             70    ║
║ C             80    ║
║ D             90    ║
║ E             70    ║
║ F             90    ║
║ G             80    ║
║ H             60    ║
╚═════════════════════╝
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
╔═══════════════════════╗
║ NoOfStudents    Marks ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ 3               90    ║
║ 2               80    ║
║ 2               70    ║
║ 1               60    ║
╚═══════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just basic aggregation.  Use the aggregation function count(), like this:

```
select count(StudentName) as NoOfStudents, marks
from tablename
group by marks
order by marks desc
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get a list of students **without any aggregation** you need to use `order by` clause. Look at example below:

```
select * from studentsAndMarks order by marks
```

if you would like to get count use the following statement:

```
select count(StudentName),Marks from studentsAndMarks group by Marks
```